# Serverless Internet-Wide Chatting Client?

Tags: client, logic, chat

Does anyone know of the logic behind a server-less chat client that would be able to interconnect **not** LAN-wide **but** internet-wide? It doesn't need to be able to detect other users world wide, it just needs to obtain some kind of unique identification to be able to connect to a user, like an IP or a unique ID of some sort.

Comment: Are you looking for a client in use already, or just wondering how one would be implemented?

Comment: I'm wondering how one would be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, you need **some** information from somewhere. You can't just turn it on and start chatting without knowing where everyone is. You might have one node that is online all the time and knows a few other nodes. The other nodes would know other nodes and those would know more, etc. It is debatable whether or not you would call that static node a "server" or not. It could just be your friend's node, or a publicly available IP. Once you are up and running, you wont need the start node anymore.

In this type of system, you would need to query your neighbors if you want some sort of identification besides IP address. An IP address has its own drawbacks as well, because you might have two people behind a router at a home DSL connection. Unique ID's would require a recursive query across the whole mesh to find out if your ID is unique.

In this type of system, you would only need to know a limited subset of people in order to chat with anyone, as you can query everyone around you (and the query happens recursively) for the location of that person. An artificial limit on the number of people stored on the local node might be implemented with a Least Recently Used algorithm, kind of like a CPU cache.

Comment: I was thinking of something like a worldwide-ranged public chat client whereas, you only get to chat with users if you know their certain identification. E.g., If I know John's unique ID, I can chat with him. If I don't know it then I can't. Only this worldwide-ranged chat is available to whomever is using the certain client. E.g. users can open their client and their friends who also has the client will open theirs on their end and they know each other's unique ID so they'd get to chat.